# AX200 Bluetooth lost after hibernate / powersafe

Tags: windows-10, boot, bluetooth, hibernate

Since I changed my M.2 WIFi card on my HB ProBook 440 G5 /w Win10 Pro (the original one was causing random crashes) to an Intel AX200 I have the problem, that when I want to recover from hibernate the PC crashes and I have to hard-reset it by long-pressing the power button. When booting again, neither WiFi nor Bluetooth are working. Re-booting brings back WiFi, but Bluetooth is permanently lost. Bluetooth is not listed in device manager (albeit greyed out when I list unused devices).
When I check the event log, I can find under Microsoft>Kernel-Boot (sorry german):

> Fehler: BL_LOG_ERROR_RES_HW_CHANGE: Hardware- oder Firmware-Einstellungen haben sich seit dem Ruhezustand geändert. Status: {Falscher Datenträger}
> Die Zieldatei einer Umbenennung befindet sich auf einem anderen Gerät als die Quelle der Umbenennung.

Unfortunately Google is not my friend on that one. Also, I tried a lot of - and combinations of - power management settings, enabling and disabling Windows power management on AX200 in device manager (Bluetooth does not have the setting), setting power management profile for network adapter to high performance, restarting BT services and so on; nothing helped.

The only 2 methods of bringing Bluetooth back were so far: Physically reinstall the original wireless card, booting windows, shuting down again, reinstalling the AX200, rebooting and everything works fine  (until next hibernate).
Also, resetting the power management profile was once successful (but is unsafe)

I'm a little out of options. I still see

- Reinstalling Win10 and hoping for the best (well...)
- Buy new Laptop (well.....)
- Migrate to Linux (have still to test if booting linux once brings BT back, but what kind of fix would that be... :D)

I hope you guys have some more ideas. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I use the same card and got a similar issue, although my setup is different.
It's on a tower PC and only Bluetooth disappears so YMMV.

The issue is that the power saving disables the hardware somehow.
I can reliably get it back by completely removing the power source for about 30s.

For a laptop this means removing the battery.